# Compute the running (cumulative) maximum for a series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Given:

```py
d = {
    'High': [954,
             953,
             952,
             955,
             956,
             952,
             951,
             950,
            ]
}
df = pandas.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to add another column which is the max at each index from the beginning. For example the desired column would be:

```py
'Max': [954, 
        954, 
        954, 
        955, 
        956, 
        956, 
        956, 
        956]
```

I tried with a pandas rolling function but the window cannot be dynamic it seems

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `cummax`

```
df.High.cummax()

0    954
1    954
2    954
3    955
4    956
5    956
6    956
7    956
Name: High, dtype: int64
```

---

```
df['Max'] = df.High.cummax()
df
```

[image]